# How to draw a linear graph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph in networkx, which I want to draw. I want to plot something like this:
[image]

I followed the instruction in the networkx documentation to draw it using the following commands:

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("path.png").
```

But, I face two problems: 1. the nodes and edges are drawn randomly, 2. the size of the canvas is fixed and the graph doesn't fit in it.

I appreciate any feedback on how I can plot this graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass node positions to the draw_networkx as a dictionary of the form: {node:[x-coordinate,y-coordinate}. You can set the size of the plot for the figure using plt.figure. Here is an example of a square:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0)])
positions = {0:[0,0],1:[1,0],2:[1,1],3:[0,1]}
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=positions)
plt.savefig("path.png")
```

[image]

Comment: or use one of the many position function that networkx offers, e.g circular layout or spring layout, e.g. see [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout)

Comment: The original poster wants to specify the position of the nodes.

Comment: that is not specifically stated in the original question just that the graph didnt fit in the plot and the connections were random. Either manually fixing or using one of the position algorithms fixes it.

Comment: I wanted something like the image I posted above. I tried to set the position manually. However, because my graph is so dense I didn't get the result I wanted. Also, I tried some of the built-in layouts, they get messy and unreadable too.